# How does Locust.io aggregate data for percentile computations?

Tags: python, locust

Consider this chart below. [image: Chart]

There's not simply a global 95th percentile or median, but multiple observations. However, requests are coming in at different times, so the method by which they're aggregated isn't clear to me. Likely options

1. All requests started within same x millisecond window
2. All requests finished within same x millisecond window

My best guess is option 1 with default bin of 1 second.